# C# HttpWebRequest to server

Tags: c#, http

I've web application which sends HTTP request to server.It uses WebRequest.Create method.
My question is.I need to change domain name or ip for HTTP request but i can't see the right place.Look at it please.

```
public WebWrapper()
{

this.UseProxy = false;
this.UA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.107 Safari/535.1";
this.Proxy = new WebProxy();
this.LastPage = "http://google.com/";
this.cookies = new CookieContainer();
}


public string httpGet(string Address, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(true)] bool Redirect)
{

string str;
try
{
    IEnumerator enumerator;
    this.WebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(Address);
    this.WebRequest.Method = "GET";
    this.WebRequest.Headers.Set("Accept-Language", "en,en-us");
    this.WebRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    this.WebRequest.CookieContainer = this.cookies;
    this.WebRequest.UserAgent = this.UA;
    this.WebRequest.Referer = this.LastPage;
```

Here's place of domain or am I wrong?

```
this.WebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(Address);
```

This constant(address),where is it in code?I am using SAE for .NET

Answer (score 1):

> This constant(address),where is it in code?

It's the first parameter for your method:

```
public string httpGet(string Address, 
                      [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(true)] bool Redirect)
```

Admittedly it *looks* like a property access, but that's just because your parameters (and method name) don't follow [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx).

So you need to find wherever you're *calling* the method, and change the first argument there.

I'd also suggest that instead of using attributes to specify optional parameters, you use the C# syntax, assuming you're using C# 4 or above:

```
// No need for "http" here - that's pretty implicit in your type name
public string DownloadText(string address, bool redirect = true)
```

Comment: Jon.I just saw an example from MSDN about    
             
WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create("your domain"); 

How can i find that WebRequest.Create(Address)?It sockets for gwc server.Here's pick 

http://fastpic.ru/view/46/2013/0716/d6c7e17cb8a6b7ef0f398a0eaef60f6a.jpg.html                           
I'd like to change this IP in Reflector but can't find right place for "string Address"

Comment: @user2277228: I have no idea what you mean. You're calling `WebRequest.Create(string)` and passing in the address that's being passed to your method. `WebRequest.Create` takes a URL, not just a domain. I'm also flagging your comment as the picture you've linked to is NSFW.

Comment: Jon.The method takes a URL.But what is that URL?   http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/690/vs8e.jpg/

Comment: How does it know that it sends requests to "google server".Where is that place?

Comment: I'm just testing with sniffer.46.174.48.38(my ip) 173.194.32.132(server)                                                 HTTP 382 GET /watch?gl=US&hl=en&client=mv-google&v=C1Xu4gGwa4k HTTP/1.1                                                             Where is set ip 173.194.32.132 at the code?I need to change it place.

Comment: @user2277228: That's just DNS resolution - you'll have "google.com" or whatever in your code, and that gets resolved into a numeric IP address. We have no idea what the rest of your code looks like - you should check the code which is calling your method.